# Two threads running concurrently in remote server

Tags: java, multithreading, jsch

I want to connect to a  server remotely, which I did through **J sch programe**,
and now, I want to run two threads concurrently, in that remote server.

One thread will be monitoring the CPU Details of the remote server,
Second Thread will be initiating an application on the same remote server.

Here is my piece of code for the main class:
`OpenSessionForRemoteConnection()` is a sub class using jsch to connect to the remote server. `GetCpuDetails` and `InitiateApllications`  are sub classes for threads.  My problem is if I create `GetCpuDetails`  as a normal subclass, then its getting the `CpuDetails` without any problem, But when I use threads, I am not getting any input stream.  I can't identify where I went wrong!

I am not an IT expert; Can anyone please help ? or suggest me any another option to do the same?

MAIN CLASS----

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String host="192.168.101.191";
    Session session = null;
    OpenSessionForRemoteConnection server1 = new      OpenSessionForRemoteConnection();

    try{
        System.out.println("calling the method for opening a new session");
        session= server1.openSession(host);
        GetCpuDetails Cpu=new GetCpuDetails (session);
        InitiateApllications initiate=new InitiateApllications(session);


        Thread t1 = new Thread(Cpu);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(initiate);       

            t1.start();
            t2.start();


        server1.closeSession();
    } catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("SESSION CLOSED--->");

}
```

Sub class to open Session to remote host:

```
  String user="user";
  String password="password"; 
  String port="22";

  Session session;

/**
 * @param args
 */

  /*
 * This method is for opening a session and establishing remote connection to the host
 */
public Session openSession (String host){

    try{

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);


        session.setPassword(password);    
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect(); // New Session for Host established and connected                

    }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }
     return session;   
}

/*
 * This method id for closing the session and disconnecting the remote server.
 */
public void closeSession(){     

    session.disconnect();
```

}

This sub class implements runnable; to get the cpu details

public class GetCpuDetails implements Runnable{

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
private Session session;

public GetCpuDetails (Session MainSession){
    //this.command=s;
    this.session=MainSession;
}

@Override
public void run() {
  processCommand(session);      
}

private  void processCommand(Session session) {

    try{
        System.out.println("get host"); 
        if(session.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("SESSION STILL CONNECTED------------->");    
        }       

        try{

            Channel channelForCPUDetails=channelForCPUDetails=session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channelForCPUDetails).setCommand("iostat");               

            channelForCPUDetails.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channelForCPUDetails).setErrStream(System.err);   

            InputStream in=channelForCPUDetails.getInputStream();
            channelForCPUDetails.connect();


            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                     System.out.printf("INSIDE WHILE->"+channelForCPUDetails.getInputStream()); 
                  int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                  if(i<0)break; 

                  System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));

                }
                if(channelForCPUDetails.isClosed()){
                  System.out.println("exit-status: "+channelForCPUDetails.getExitStatus());
                  break;
                }
              }

            channelForCPUDetails.disconnect();        


    }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }   


}


private void suspendThread(){       
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are closing the session too early like this:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
server1.closeSession();
```

You are injecting the session into your threads. You can't guarantee that your threads would use those sessions on server before you close your session in your main thread. I would suggest you wait for your threads to complete (either via [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or [CountdownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for e.g.) and then you close the session.

Answer (score 0):

As SMA said, you are exiting before the threads are finished. You need to wait for these threads to finish. You can do this by 'joining' to the started threads. Change your code to this:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();

//Wait for the threads to finish
t1.join();
t2.join();

server1.closeSession();
```